# How to add value to a cell in a datagridview using a query?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a bound datagridview that has an unbound column. I'm using cellformatting to look up the Employee ID in the same row to return the employee's name from a different datatable.

I get everything working fine, the only problem is that i can only get one part of the name to show either the first name, middel, last, but not all together.

This is the code i have so far (I'm very new to coding, all that i have so far has been from forums or research only, so please comment your answer):

```
If dgvr.Cells(0).Value IsNot Nothing AndAlso dgvr.Cells(0).Value IsNot DBNull.Value Then
        Dim empID As Integer = CInt(dgvr.Cells(0).Value)
        Dim qry = From dr As PersonalObraDataSet.PersonalObRow In _PersonalObraDataSet.PersonalOb _
        Where (dr.cdTrabajador = empID)
        'If qry.Count > 0 Then
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value = qry.First.Apellido1
        'DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value = qry.First.Nombre2
    End If
    'End If
```

Comment: What kind of data does `qry` return? is `qry.First.Apellido1` a string? Do you want to also show something like `qry.Middle.Apellido1` and `qry.Last.Apellido1` ? in one cell? in multiple cells?

Comment: qry returns a string the employee's first name. Each component of the name is in a different column and i would like to display the 4 parts in one cell of the unbound column. It would be qry= Name1 Name2 Last1 Last2. This would look like John Denver Smith Jones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine strings with & operator. It would be something like

```
DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value = qry.First.Nombre2 & " " & qry.First.Apellido1 & " " &  qry.First.SegundoNombre3
```

Comment: IT doesn't work it tells me that end of statement is expected after the 2nd " any ideas? do they have to be in parenthesis?

Comment: Put another & after that second " . Yuiry's answer is good, he just made a typo

Comment: I'll have to check it when I get back to my computer. I'll let you guys know and mark it as answer. Thanks

Comment: Of course! I tried it, but i just used the Name1 & instead of the full query.first statement. Thanks!